# Jquery Sortable only fires after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've integrated the jquery "sortable" feature into my website, and it works perfectly with one minor exception. It only works after I click once anywhere on the page. The section of the page the sortable elements are found is loaded after an ajax query, so I'm using the "on" function. I'd love to figure out how to get this to work without having to click first.

```js
$(document).on("mousedown.sortable", "#container", function() {
  $("#container").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");
      $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<div id="mainContainer">
  <ul id="container">
    <li id="item-1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item-2">Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For anyone reading this later, the key to the accepted answer is to have the portion of JQuery code loaded every time the portion of HTML is loaded into the document via AJAX, rather than in a "main" piece of code that's loaded the first time the page itself is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the mousedown event handler (removed here), since this is causing the sortable to only be added *after* you do your initial click (as described by yourself)

```js
$("#container").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'myurl'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <ul id="container">
    <li id="item-1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item-2">Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Lee, thanks, but since the HTML is loaded after the initial page load via a separate AJAX call, these elements do not previously exist and that code will not work.

Comment: OK, that's easy. Just call the `sortable` code after you have added your new elements.

Comment: I'm not following - are you suggesting that I should have this jquery code called in the php that's brought in from the AJAX load? The content of the div containing the sortable list may be replaced and reloaded several times. Will loading the jquery script multiple times create a conflict?

Comment: if you are only replacing the items within `container` with your AJAX call then you can just call the `sortable` code once. If you're obliterating `container` with new content then you will need to add a new handler after you change your HTML/DOM.

Comment: I added an ID to the overarching DIV for clarity. The contents are replaced via a separate call such as:  $("#mainContainer").load("listCode.php");

Comment: ok, so if you're obliterating the div that the `sortable` relates to, you will need call sortable again after you have replaced your content. Perhaps it would be better if you explained in your question what it is you're trying to achieve...

Comment: It does work to include this as a separate script and simply have it called again every time this portion of content is loaded.